# Getting my reward in Zeryphesh

Tags: torchlight-2

I remember travelling in the Frosted Hills and encountering a group of injured Zeraphis and their ambassador Lord Taldimut.

He offered two quests, which I completed in due time, the Zeraphi Envoy, and the Lost Key.

After I finished the Lost Key, he said:

> This is it! The Golden Gear! I thank you on behalf of all the Zeraphi
>   people. This might just have tipped the battle in our favor! I can
>   only offer you this as payment, but if you are ever in Zeryphesh, come
>   find me and I will grant you a proper reward!

I've already reached Zeryphesh, and I still haven't found him.  Does he actually appear as an NPC and give a reward? Does he only come after certain missions or during a certain time? Or does he not show up? (I'm currently on the quest where you have to complete favors for the Djinn)

Comment: Huh, never recalled this at all but I would presume that the reward was either left out of the game by accident or that one other Zeraphi guy you help out with his problem (Shadow of the Skara quest) actually was meant to give you the reward (which in that case would be getting access to that one girl merchant.). Either case I am not too sure that it is actually right. Interesting tidbit to research though.

Comment: Ah, good question, I was wondering the same myself. I finished the game, and I still haven't heard of that.

Comment: I remember him saying that, but I can't remember whether anything happened with it.

Comment: The problem is that NPC never makes it back to Zeryphesh in the timeframe of the game.  Even post Act 4 you can go back and visit him in the Frosted Hills and he will be forever resting in the same place, while the other NPC's will politely ask you what the bleep you are doing back in Act I.

Comment: I am going to now presume that he might be used in a future patch perhaps, the developers did hint at adding New Game + content in a forum post recently, which I would presume might relate to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed just words. There was a quest called The Key To Victory that was unfinished and thus does not appear in the game which explains this. In this quest, you encounter Taldimut again in the Ossean Wastes where he asks you to use the Golden Gear to re-activate the portal in the Celestial Armory dungeon.

The quest can be found in the Unearthed Arcana mod which fixes and adds this as well as a lot of other content that's not used or unfinished in the game.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, it appears that that line from Lord Taldimut is simply words, and does not have any bearing on the game. The only reward for helping him is the two subsequent quests.